# Program idle while comparing two dates in while statement

Tags: python, datetime, time

Don't know how to properly describe my problem, but when I compare two datetime objects in while statement the whole program stops working.
I have a method `work()`

```
import time
import datetime
def work():
    now = None
    intr = 10.0
    d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    least_time = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today(), datetime.time(10, 10, 00))
    finish = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today(), datetime.time(10, 10, 20))
    if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 0:
        least_time = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today(), datetime.time(11,10,00))
        finish = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today(), datetime.time(11,10,20))
    while d <= finish:
        d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        if intr > 1 and d >= least_time:
            intr = 1
            print("Interval set to 1 sec")
        if now == None:
            now = time.time()
        if time.time() - now >= intr:  
            print("Work")
            print("_____")        
            now = None
    print("End")
```

And, if I call `print()` or something else before that method:

```
print("1")
print("2")
print("3")
work()
```

The program just idle and do nothing.

Comment: it's not clear what your objective is but putting this line `        print d, finish, least_time, intr` just after the while loop shows that your script is running and least_time and finish aren't probaby what you thought they ought to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens depends on your current time zone.
The call to `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` gives a datetime in UTC,
whereas `datetime.datetime.today()` gives you current datetime for your time zone (which you machine has):

Changing:

```
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

to:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()
```

or to:

```
d = datetime.datetime.today()
```

would fix your problem.